# How to change the height of 2 by 2 figures in rmarkdown

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, figure

I want to make each figure longer in heights under 2 by 2 style. Any idea, please?

```
attach(mtcars)
par(mfrow=c(2,2))
plot(wt,mpg, main="Scatterplot of wt vs. mpg")
plot(wt,disp, main="Scatterplot of wt vs disp")
hist(wt, main="Histogram of wt")
boxplot(wt, main="Boxplot of wt")
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set `fig.height` in the code chunk.

````
```{r, fig.height = 10}
attach(mtcars)
par(mfrow=c(2,2))
plot(wt,mpg, main="Scatterplot of wt vs. mpg")
plot(wt,disp, main="Scatterplot of wt vs disp")
hist(wt, main="Histogram of wt")
boxplot(wt, main="Boxplot of wt")
```
````

[image: fig]